# Trying to parse a Putnam solution from 1995

Tags: binomial-theorem

I’m having trouble parsing the solution for the [1995 Putnam](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1995s.pdf), question A2. The proof proceeds:

The easiest proof uses
``big-O'' notation and the fact that $(1+x)^{1/2} = 1 + x/2 +
O(x^{2})$ for $|x|<1$. (Here $O(x^{2})$ means bounded by a constant
times $x^{2}$.) Me: That’s all well and good, and I can arrive at that by the generalized binomial theorem.

The proof continues:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x} &= x^{1/2}(\sqrt{1+a/x} - 1) \\
&= x^{1/2}(1 + a/2x + O(x^{-2})),
\end{align*}

It would appear that’s an error; it would appear the proof writer dropped the minus 1.

But it continues, hence

$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a} - \sqrt{x}} = x^{1/4} (a/4x + O(x^{-2}))$

Which I’m at a loss how to arrive at.

Comment: For what it’s worth, you aren’t the first person to have asked about this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020837/question-about-solution-to-putnam-1995-a2

Comment: I am not sure if you have copied things properly. Why do we have $O(x^{2})$ in one place and $O(x^{-2})$ at others?

Comment: Note that on the right side of the first equation, x is in the denominator, whereas at the top, x is in the numerator.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Not OP, but that is because the new "$x$" is now $a/x$, so when you substitute that in $O(x^2)$ becomes $O(a^2/x^2)$, which is the same as $O(x^{-2})$

Comment: You should show the question.  I looked up the reference and it doesn't appear to be what you want.  Also, where is the proof that you refer to?

Comment: Whoops. Thank you. https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1995s.pdf

Comment: all right except for a trifle. Delete extra 1 and have  $\ldots \sqrt{(a/2)x^{-\frac 12}(1+O(x^{-1}))}=\sqrt{a/2}x^{-\frac 14}(1+O(x^{-1}))\ldots$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, so the first step is clearly a mistake with them dropping the $-1$. However, I'm going to try to explain what they may have done, even though it doesn't make sense. First, let's start with their (albeit wrong) equation:

$$\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}(1+\frac{a}{2x}+O(x^{-2}))$$
Now, take the square root:
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=[x^{1/2}(1+\frac{a}{2x}+O(x^{-2}))]^{1/2}$$

Distribute the exponent:
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}[(1+\frac{a}{2x}+O(x^{-2}))]^{1/2}$$

Now, the second expression on the right is in the form of $(1+z)^{1/2}$, so I will use the following formula:

$$(1+z)^{1/2}=1+\frac z 2+O(z^2)\rightarrow \\ (1+\frac a{2x}+O(x^{-2}))^{1/2}=1+\frac{a}{4x}+\frac{1}{2}O(x^{-2})+O(\frac{a^2}{4x^2})=1+\frac{a}{4x}+O(x^{-2})$$

Thus, we get:

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}(1+\frac{a}{4x}+O(x^{-2}))$$

Oh, and remember that $-1$ we dropped in the first step? Let's try adding that back in here, because...why not?

$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}(1+\frac{a}{4x}+O(x^{-2})-1)$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x}}=x^{1/4}(\frac{a}{4x}+O(x^{-2}))$$
Thus, we get the same equation they did, and we only had to make two mathematical errors to get there!

Comment: I like that you were able to decipher what the original proof writer most likely meant.  Thank you for that.